# Teamviewer scrolling speed

Tags: macos, remote-desktop

Back To My Mac recently stopped working for me, so I started using TeamViewer to access my home Mac from the outside world.

It works great, for the most part. One thing that is frustrating me though is scroll speed. Regardless of what I use (magic mouse, track-pad), scrolling in the remote computer is too fast. It just jumps from the top of the list to the bottom instantly. I don't see any speed tuning controls in TeamViewer, and when I'm connected remotely there are no mice or track-pads displayed in System Preferences, so you can't adjust speed there either.

Can I slow down the scroll when my network connection has delays to avoid over shooting?

Answer (score 2):

I have a temporary solution. You can install "Smart Scroll mac" and add specific setting for Teamviewer like follows (all other settings=off).
[image]

Then, you can use the trackpad in teamviewer normally. Btw, I recommend you buying this app.